# Error: Uncaught (in promise): ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 24 failed

Tags: angular8

We have migrated application from angular 4.4 to 8.2.

And also we implemented lazy loading, it seems working fine in local environment with (PROD mode).

But after deployment in different server, it throws chunk files not found.

The command we used :

```
ng build --prod=true --cross-origin=anonymous --source-map=false
ng build --prod=true --cross-origin=anonymous --source-map=false
Error: Uncaught (in promise): ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 24 failed.
```